# Show the usual metric on $C([0,1])$ does not give rise to a complete metric space.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I know that I need to show there is a Cauchy sequence which converges to a point outwith $C[0,1]$ to show this. Is this the right way of going about it (I can only think of $f_n (x) = x_n = \frac{1}{n}$ as an example:

Let $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$. Then for $n \geq m > 0$ $|x_n - x_m| = \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{m} $

$= \frac{m - n}{nm} < \frac{m}{nm} = \frac{1}{n} <\epsilon$
Set $N = \frac{1}{\epsilon}$ then for $n \geq m > \epsilon$ $\frac{1}{n} \leq \frac{1}{m} < \epsilon$ Hence $\frac{1}{n}$ is Cauchy.

Taking the limit as $n \to \infty$ $f_n (x) = 0$ for $0<n<1$ and $1 for n = 1$. Thus there is a discontinuity at 1, hence it cannot converge.

I feel this is the right track but think I've gone wrong somewhere, can someone spot where? Thanks

Comment: What is the "usual metric" supposed to be? For me, the usual metric on $C([0,1])$ is the one induced by the supremum norm, and that makes it a complete metric space.

Comment: the usual metric we're given:$d_2 (x)=(\int_0^1|f(x) - g(x)|)^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Comment: I'm not understanding your example. At first, it seems like $n$ is  a positive integer, so you are looking at constant functions $1/n$. After that, you are taking $0<n<1$... It would be nice if you explained a little better what you are trying to do here.

Comment: I was meaning it as a constant function, in which case the second part of the argument would not hold... I am suspecting now that my function would not be a counter example as I have almost 'made up' a discontinuity

Comment: You can't get there with constant functions, since the space of constant functions is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, which you know to be complete.

Comment: How about $f_n(x)=x^n$?

Comment: @Bryan. That almost works, but you need a little more care.  Over the unit interval, that sequence actually converges to the constant function $0$.

Comment: I am sure that would work if I take the absolute value (similarly to what I did above) but I am now not sure if that is the right way to go about it. Should I be taking $(\int_0^1|x^n - x^m|)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and showing that approaches zero?

Comment: Ah yes, that's right. It's in the topology of pointwise convergence that that sequence converges to a discontinuous function.

Comment: @Bryan :$$\int_{0}^{1}\vert x^{n}-0\vert\,\textrm{d}x = \int_{0}^{1}x^{n}\, \textrm{d}x = \left[\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\right]_{0}^{1} = \frac{1}{n+1}\to 0$$
This sequence converges in the space given (to the constant zero function).

Comment: x^n converges to $\left\{ \begin{matrix}
   0\quad \text{if}\ 0\le x<1  \\
   1\quad \ \text{if}\quad x=1\quad   \\
\end{matrix} \right$. which is not continuous

Comment: @Pete: That function is distance zero from the zero function.  To make this approach work, you need to converge to a function with an *essential* discontinuity.

Comment: I appologize. I am half a** at math but whole a** at typesetting with Tex.

Comment: Pointwise  convergence.

Comment: Yes, but the metric we are using here is not the metric of pointwise convergence, but rather $L_1$ convergence.

Comment: The formula $d(f,g) = (\int_0^1 |f(x) - g(x)|\, dx)^{1/2}$ is neither "usual" nor a "metric".  I think most would agree that the usual metric is $sup_x |f(x) - g(x)|$, and $(\int_0^1 |f(x) - g(x)|^2\, dx)^{1/2}$ defines the $L^2$ metric; perhaps the latter is what you want?

Comment: Hmm I am getting confused with my definitions, I think $L^2$ is what I want indeed. My apologies for the confusion.

Comment: If we use L1 or L2 convergence then we are talking about equivalence classes with a.e. equal, or equal except on sets of measure zero and discontinuities are irrelevent. If we want only continuous functions we need use the sup norm.

Answer (score -2):

Start with a nice discontinuous function $f$ - something like the step function at $1/2$.  Find the Fourier series for this function.  The series should converge to $f$ in your metric (and not to any other continuous function, since the discontinuity is essential).  But the sequence of partial sums is made up of continuous functions, and so is contained in $C(0,1)$.

Or, if you don't like Fourier series, try approximating the same step function with a sequence of piecewise continuous (or even piecewise linear) functions.

Comment: $$f_{n}(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ccl}0 & \textrm{if} & x \in \left[0, \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right] \\
\frac{n+1}{2}\left(x-\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)\right) & \textrm{if} & x\in \left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n+1}\right) \\
1 & \textrm{if} & x\in \left[\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n+1}, 1 \right]\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: Here's how to make it work with those monomials:
$$f_{n}(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
(2x)^{n} & \textrm{if} & x\in \left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right] \\
1 & \textrm{if} & x\in \left(\frac{1}{2},1\right]
\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: And with exponentials:
$$f_{n}(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
\textrm{e}^{n\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)} & \textrm{if} & x\in \left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right] \\
1 & \textrm{if} & x\in \left(\frac{1}{2},1\right]
\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: And the Fourier example: 
$$f_{n}(x)=\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{2\pi(2k-1)x}{2k-1}.$$